# indexOf is not a function on an array in jQuery grep

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my function

```
function search(){
  var searchValue = $('#search-bar').val();

  console.log(Array.isArray(initData[0].body)); //true

  returnArr = $.grep(initData[0].body, function( element, idx ) {
      return element.indexOf(searchValue) != -1; // error: indexOf is not a function
  });

}
```

I'm getting `indexOf` is not a function.

I know initData[0].body is an array (see code)

Comment: Have you tried doing a `console.log` on `element`? (Hint: it's not an array)

Comment: Thanks. Should I delete this question now? The answer was simple

Comment: check for console.log(typeof(element.indexOf) === 'function')); it will not be function.

Comment: No need to delete. You can rephrase the question to ask how to get what exactly you are looking for. It's not too clear as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling indexOf on the element variable which is an item inside your initData[0].body array. Make sure element is an array type if you are calling indexOf on it.